# How to uninstall Janus?

Tags: vim, plugins, janus

I can't figure out how to uninstall [Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus). I'd really like to just go back to plain VIM and MacVim. I could try to just remove the ~/.janus directory, but since Janus took a while to install I imagine there are other things and places where it installed stuff. Does anyone know a complete way to install Janus?

Comment: Never used Janus, but (and this is really a guessing answer) why not just uninstall Vim and then install it again. Installation-wise, Vim is really rather self-contained: Vim in one, _vimrc+vimfiles in other place.

Comment: +1 for scraping Janus.

Comment: @ldigas, installing and removing Vim won't help: Janus is installed in `$HOME` where the install process does nothing at all.

Comment: @romainl - I ment uninstall Vim AND delete all Janus files.

Comment: OK, my comment still applies, though, because Janus doesn't touch Vim in anyway. No need to uninstall Vim.

Comment: @romainl - Yes, okey. You got a point there.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Janus is just a collection of vim settings and plugins which are stored in the `~/.vim` directory. Janus has a [bootstrap installer](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/blob/master/bootstrap.sh) that basically renames anything in that directory to `whatever.old` and then clones itself into that directory. So the counter effect would be to delete anything that doesn't end in `.old` and then take the `.old` off of everything. You could accomplish this with these commands.

```
cd ~/.vim
find . -not -name \*.old -delete
find . -name \*.old | while read file; do mv "$file" "${file%%.old}"; done
```

Comment: This is not only a simple recipe, it's also a mini-masterclass in elegant Bash. Thanks for the inspiration!

Comment: I think the Janus install also creates some links that might need cleaning up: 
~/.vimrc -> ~/.vim/janus/vim/vimrc
~/.gvimrc -> ~/.vim/janus/vim/gvimrc

Answer (score 17):

To uninstall janus, you can do this:

- remove ~/.vim, ~/.vimrc and ~/.gvimrc - You can keep the rc files if you need the customization.
- Remove ~/.vimrc.before and ~/.vimrc.after.
- Remove the ~/.janus/ directory

That should be all.

The above process will remove all your customizations etc and all the plugins as well. So, make sure you delete only what you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, installing the `janus` causes you to have new `.vim` folder, new `.vimrc` and `.gvimrc` file which they are linked file to `/Users/amerllica/.vim/janus/vim/vimrc` and `/Users/amerllica/.vim/janus/vim/gvimrc`. Maybe `.vimrc.after` and `.vimrc.before` your have on your home directory.

**Don't** worry, the installation flow keep you previous `.vim` path and the `.vimrc` file on **`.vim.old`** and **`.vimrc.old`** file.

So without any doubt do below actions:

```
rm -rf .vim .vimrc .gvimrc
```

then:

```
mv .vim.old .vim
mv .vimrc.old .vimrc
mv .gvimrc.old .gvimrc // if you had installed Gvim
```

If you have `.vimrc.before` or `.vimrc.after` delete them by below commands:

```
rm -rf .vimrc.before .vimrc.after
```

Also, please do not forget to remove *janus*:

```
rm -rf ~/.janus
```

I hope, this answer helps you.